# Java selenium to traverse accordion tree based on the pattern

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Below is a sample accordion using some divs very similar to a directory. Suppose I want to go till

How can I select Coffee and it may appear in other accordions, all I have to traverse the accordion based on my input.

> Beverages > Water > Coffee

public void walk(WebElement ele,String patterns){
Sting pattern[] = patterns.split(">");

}

method call will like, walk(someparent, "Beverages>Tea>Green Tea");